# Proof of $\dim\ \ker\ (f \circ g) \le \dim\ \ker\ (f) + \dim\ \ker\ (g)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In my lecture notes I have an inequality for any linear transformations $f: X \to X$, $g: X \to X$ for any finite-dimensional vector space $X$:
$$\dim\ \ker\ (f \circ g) \le \dim\ \ker\ (f) + \dim\ \ker\ (g)$$

Can anyone help me with proofing it?
Of course I know basic equality: $\dim\ \ker\ f + \dim\ {\rm im} \ f = \dim\ X$, but I do not know any inequality, which involves dimension of transpormations, therefore I do not even know where to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you write expression for $\ker(f \circ g) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g:V\to W$ and $f:W\to X$. So, $f\circ g:V\to X$. Note that $\ker(f\circ  g)=g^{-1}(\ker f)$. Let $V=g^{-1}(\ker f)$.  This is a subspace of $V$, and $g(V')\subseteq\ker f$.  Note that $\ker g\subseteq V'$.
$$\operatorname{dim}V=\operatorname{dim}(\ker g)+\dim(g(V')),$$
and
$$\dim(g(V'))=\dim(\ker f|_{g(V')})+\dim(f(g(V')).$$

Since $V'=\ker(f\circ g)$, $\dim(f(g(V'))=0$, and $\dim(f|_{g(V')})=\dim(\ker f\cap g(V'))\le\dim\ker f$, we get the desired inquality.

Comment: Shouln't it be $g^{-1}(\ker f)$.? Also, where is $f$ described?

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Silly me.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Ok, at the first look I though that I understand, but now I am not sure, how do we know $ker(f) = g(V)$? (so that later we can say $ker(f) = im(g)$ since  $g(V) =im (g)$)

Comment: You're right, I was a bit careless.  I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I think based on Tim Raczkowski's idea, we can construct a more succinct proof:

Again, let $~g: V \to W,~ f: W \to X$ with $ V' = \text{ker}(fg) \subseteq V $.

The important point to note is that $ V' = \text{ker}(fg) = g^{-1}(\text{ker}f) $ so that $ g(V') \subseteq \text{ker}(f) $.  Hence, $\text{dim}(g(V')) \leq \text{nullity}(f)$.  By the Dimension Theorem, $$ \text{dim}(V') = \text{dim}(\text{ker}~ g|_{V'}) + \text{dim}(\text{Im}~g|_{V'}).$$
Now, $\text{dim}(\text{Im}~g|_{V'}) = \text{dim}(g(V'))$ and from above, $\text{dim}(g(V')) \leq \text{nullity}(f)$.
Thus, $$ \text{dim}(V') \leq \text{dim}(\text{ker}~ g|_{V'}) +  \text{nullity}(f). $$
Since $ \text{ker}~ g \subseteq V'$, $ \text{ker}~g|_{V'} = \text{ker} ~g $ which implies $\text{dim}(\text{ker}~g|_{V'} ) = \text{dim}(\text{ker} ~g)$.

Finally, $$ \text{nullity}~fg = \text{dim}(V') \leq \text{nullity}~g + \text{nullity}~f $$
as needed.