# Prove that $\dim (\ker f^{2})\leq 2\dim (\ker f)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an  $n$-dimensional vector space and  $f: V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator. Prove that $\dim (\ker f^{2})\leq 2\dim  (\ker f)$.

---

I think $\dim (V)= \dim (\ker f)+\dim (\text{im }f)$ will be useful for this.

However, the question I want to ask is how can I identify $f^{2}$ in the problem. Then, can you help me to show the relation between $\dim (\ker f^{2})$ and $2\dim  (\ker f)$? Especially the $"="$ in the inequality.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note $f^2:=f\circ f$. Then apply this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607387/proof-of-dim-ker-f-circ-g-le-dim-ker-f-dim-ker-g?rq=1

Comment: This follows from applying rank-nullity to Sylvester's Rank Inequality